# Divide Mesh grid by a bisector, MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a **piecewise** function, where domain changes for each case. The function is as follows:

> For
>
> (x,y)greater than Divider v= f(x,y) (A1)
>
> (x,y)less than Divider v = g(x,y)        (A2)

The location of the divider changes with tilt angle of the rectangle given in figures 1 and 2.[Figure 1 & 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZhfi.png) The divider will always be a bisector of the rectangle. For example, the divider makes an angle (alpha + 90) with the horizontal.
**If the rectangle makes an angle 0**, it's easy to implement above functions as I can create meshgrid from

> x =B to C & y = A to D for A1
>
> x =A to B & y = A to D for A2

However, when the angles for the rectangle are different, I can't figure out how to create the mesh to calculate the function v using the algorithm A1 and A2 above.

I was thinking of using some inequality and using the equation of the line (as I have the co-ordinates for the center of the rectangle and the angle of tilt). But, I can't seem to think of a way to do it for all angles (for example , slope of pi/2 as in the first figure, yields infinity). Even if I do create some kind of inequality, I can't create a mesh. 
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZhfi.png)Please help me with this problem. I have wasted a lot of time on this. It seems to be out of my reach

```
%% Constants
Angle1=0;
Angle1=Angle1.*pi./180;

rect_center=0; % in m
rect_length=5; % in m
rect_width=1; % in m
rect_strength=1.8401e-06;

Angle2=0;
Angle2 =Angle2.*pi./180;


  %% This code calculates the outer coordinates of the rectangle by using the central point

% the following code calculates the vertices   
vertexA=rect_center+(-rect_width./2.*exp(1i.*1.5708)-rect_length./2).*exp(1i.*Angle2);
vertexA=[vertexA,vertexA+2.*(rect_width./2.*exp(1i.*1.5708)).*exp(1i.*Angle2)];
vertexB=rect_center+(-rect_width./2.*exp(1i.*1.5708)+rect_length./2).*exp(1i.*Angle2);
vertexB=[vertexB,vertexB+2.*(rect_width./2.*exp(1i.*1.5708)).*exp(1i.*Angle2)];

za1=vertexA(1:numel(vertexA)/2);
za2=vertexA(1+numel(vertexA)/2:numel(vertexA));
zb1=vertexB(1:numel(vertexB)/2);
zb2=vertexB(1+numel(vertexB)/2:numel(vertexB));
arg1=exp(-1i.*Angle2);



%% This Section makes the two equations necessary for making the graphs 


    syms var_z    

    % Equation 1
    Eqn1(var_z)=1.5844e-07.*exp(-1i.*Angle1).*var_z./9.8692e-13;



    % subparts of the Equation 2 
    A = 1.0133e+12.*(-1i.*rect_strength.*exp(-1i*Angle2)./(2*pi.*rect_length.*rect_width*0.2));
    ZA1 = var_z+za1-2*rect_center;
    ZA2 = var_z+za2-2*rect_center;
    ZB1 = var_z+zb1-2*rect_center;
    ZB2 = var_z+zb2-2*rect_center;


   ZAA2 = log(abs(ZA2)) + 1i*mod(angle(ZA2),2*pi);
   ZAA1 = log(abs(ZA1)) + 1i*mod(angle(ZA1),2*pi);
   ZBB1 = log(abs(ZB1)) + 1i*mod(angle(ZB1),2*pi);
   ZBB2 = log(abs(ZB2)) + 1i*mod(angle(ZB2),2*pi);

   %Equation 2 ; this is used for the left side of the center
   Eqn2= A*(ZA2*(log(ZA2)-1)-(ZA1*(log(ZA1)-1))+(ZB1*(log(ZB1)-1))-(ZB2*(log(ZB2)-1)));
   %Equation 3 ; this is used for the right side of the center
   Eqn3 = A.*(ZA2*(ZAA2-1)-(ZA1*(ZAA1-1))+(ZB1*(ZBB1-1))-(ZB2*(ZBB2-1)));


    %Equation 4 :Add Equation 2 and Equation 1; this is used for the left side of the center
    Eqn4 = matlabFunction(Eqn1+Eqn2,'vars',var_z);
    %Equation 5: Add Equation 3 and Equation 1; this is used for the right side of the center
    Eqn5 = matlabFunction(Eqn1+Eqn3,'vars',var_z);






    %% Prepare for making the plots

    minx=-10;     %min x coordinate 
    maxx=10;      %max x coordinate 
    nr_x=1000;    %nr x points
    miny=-10;     %min y coordinate 
    maxy=10;      %max y coordinate 
    nr_y=1000;    %nr y points

    %This vector starts from left corner (minx) to the middle of the plot surface,
    %The middle of the plot surface lies at the center of the rectange
    %created earlier
    xvec1=minx:(rect_center-minx)/(0.5*nr_x-1):rect_center;

    %This vector starts from middle to the right corner (maxx) of the plot surface,
    %The middle of the plot surface lies at the center of the rectange
    %created earlier
    xvec2=rect_center:(maxx-rect_center)/(0.5*nr_x-1):maxx;


    %the y vectors start from miny to maxy
    yvec1=miny:(maxy-miny)/(nr_y-1):maxy;
    yvec2=miny:(maxy-miny)/(nr_y-1):maxy;


    % create mesh from above vectors
    [x1,y1]=meshgrid(xvec1,yvec1);
    [x2,y2]=meshgrid(xvec2,yvec2);


     z1=x1+1i*y1;
     z2=x2+1i*y2;



    % Calculate the above function using equation 4 and equation 5 using the mesh created above  
    r1 = -real(Eqn5(z1));  
    r2 = -real(Eqn4(z2));

    %Combine the calculated functions
    Result = [r1 r2];

    %Combine the grids
    x = [x1 x2];
    y = [y1 y2];

 % plot contours  
 [c,h]=contourf(x,y,Result(:,:,1),50,'LineWidth',1);
 % plot the outerboundary of the rectangle
 line_x=real([vertexA;vertexB]);
 line_y=imag([vertexA;vertexB]);
 line(line_x,line_y,'color','r','linestyle',':','linewidth',5)
```

**The final Figure is supposed to look like this**.[Final Expected Figure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woHyt.jpg)

Comment: Is the divider always a line? If you can write it in the form `v(x,y) = a*x + b*y + c = 0` then for any point `(x,y)` the value of `v(x,y)` is positive for values on one side of the line and negative for values on the other side.

Comment: If you could post some self-contained code demonstrating the method working in the 0 or 90 degree case then I may be able to help further. I'm not sure what output you expect from the description you gave.

Comment: Added the code. Thank you very much for trying to help. The code works when Angle2 = 0 , but otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: It looks like to me like `Angle2` defines the rectangle and `Angle1` is supposed define the divider. But your comment indicates the reverse. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which angle defines the dividing line so I assume it's `Angle1`. It looks like logical indexing is the way to go here. Instead of creating two separate mesh grids we simply create the entire mesh grid then partition it into two sets and operate on each independently.

```
%% Prepare for making the plots

minx=-10;     %min x coordinate 
maxx=10;      %max x coordinate 
nr_x=1000;    %nr x points
miny=-10;     %min y coordinate 
maxy=10;      %max y coordinate 
nr_y=1000;    %nr y points

% create full mesh grid
xvec=linspace(minx,maxx,nr_x);
yvec=linspace(miny,maxy,nr_y);
[x,y]=meshgrid(xvec,yvec);

% Partition mesh based on divider line
% Assumes the line passes through (ox,oy) with normal vector defined by Angle1
ox = rect_center;
oy = rect_center;
a = cos(Angle1);
b = sin(Angle1);
c = -(a*ox + b*oy);
% use logical indexing to opperate on the appropriate parts of the mesh
idx1 = a*x + b*y + c < 0;
idx2 = ~idx1;

z = zeros(size(x));
z(idx1) = x(idx1) + 1i*y(idx1);
z(idx2) = x(idx2) + 1i*y(idx2);

% Calculate the above function using equation 4 and equation 5
%   using the mesh created above  
Result = zeros(size(z));
Result(idx1) = -real(Eqn5(z(idx1)));
Result(idx2) = -real(Eqn4(z(idx2)));
```

For example with `Angle1 = 45` and `Angle2 = 45` we get the following indexing

```
>> contourf(x,y,idx1);
>> line(line_x,line_y,'color','r','linestyle',':','linewidth',5);
```

[image]

where the yellow region uses `Eqn5` and the blue region uses `Eqn4`. This agrees with the example you posted but I don't know what the resulting contour map for other cases is supposed to look like.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this. But the figure doesn't look anything like that. I have edited to include the picture.

Comment: The code I posted is meant to replace the codeblock titled "%% Prepare for making the plots". Appoligies if this wasn't clear. The figure I posted is just to demonstrate the parts of the mesh that are computed using Eqn5 and Eqn4 respectively. The resulting image (which matches yours for 0 angle) didn't look correct to me for 45 degrees which indicates there may be an issue with Eqn4 or Eqn5 but I don't know what they represent. The figure demonstrates that the indexing isn't the problem. I also assumed the meanings of Angle1/2 since you never responded to the comment in the original post.

Comment: Angle is correct. Yes, my code seems to have some other issue. the snippet you have provided seems to work well. Thank!